# zend framework and PHP include('');

Tags: zend-framework

I want a registration section for users on the homepage of my site, but I don't want it to be like all other functions where I click a link to get to the controller.. I want the form to be on the homepage along with other content.. In PHP I would do this by creating the function and then just simply include('path/to/php/file.php')

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html). Rob Allen has a [great tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-view-helpers/) about them. And I guess what you are searching for is more information about the logging in and authentication. Matthew Weier O'Phinney has a really good [tutorial](http://mwop.net/blog/165-Login-and-Authentication-with-Zend-Framework.html) about it too. Matthew's tutorial is using view helpers too but they are not explained detailed enough. So it is probably better if you read Rob's tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

The form can be on the homepage even if it submits to another controller. Or you could create a standalone PHP script and include it in (probably from your view) if you prefer to work this way.